# Frameworks deleted from Finder (Xcode 4.5.1, Mountain Lion)

Tags: ios, xcode

Due to some unknown reason (certainly not due to my own doing), I have lost 4-5 frameworks. They do not show up in Finder and now of course do not show up in `Xcode` either.

I am using `Xcode 4.5.1` and `Mountain Lion`. The frameworks are `CoreData`, Security and a few more important ones.

I did look here. They are really gone. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks.`

How may I recover them. Tomorrow morning, I would ask someone to locate them and send them over to me. But what other option may I have in the meantime? Any place where I can just download them?

Comment: Reinstall Xcode. If you really need the 4.5.1 version, download it from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action.

Comment: With the kind of internet speed I have right now, sadly really not an option for me :/

Comment: I don't think there are more options, if you don't have a backup.